# how to connect two apps with socket.io

Tags: socket.io, electron, expo

So I have one electron-express-socket.io app that runs all fine.
I now need to connect an EXPO app to the socket.io with ("socket.io-client").

They are on different ports.

1. Eelectron-express-socket.io = http://localhost:3000/
2. EXPO app = http://localhost:19006/

I've tried this
https://socket.io/docs/v2/handling-cors/

ELECTRON:

```
const socketio = require('socket.io');
class WebSocket {
  socket = null
  allClients = [];

  socketOptions = {
    'path': '/ws',
    'pingInterval': 10000,
    "handlePreflightRequest": (req, res) => {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "my-custom-header",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": false
      });
      res.end();
    }
  }

  constructor(httpServer) {
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    // this.socket = socketio(httpServer, this.socketOptions);
    //-------------------------------------------------------
    this.socket = socketio();
    this.socket.attach(httpServer, this.socketOptions);
    //-------------------------------------------------------

    this.socket.on('connection', (client) => {
      this.onConnection(client);
    });
    this.socket.on('error', this.onClientError);
  }
}
```

EXPO APP:

```
import socketIOClient from "socket.io-client";
const ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:3000/";

export default function App() {
 //-- SocketIO
 const [response, setResponse] = useState("");
 useEffect(() => {
   const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT, {
    withCredentials: false,
  });

   socket.on("currentTime", data => {

     setResponse(data);
   });

 }, []);

//-- SocketIO

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{response}Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
```

I've also tired

```
socketOptions = {
    'path': '/ws',
    'pingInterval': 10000,
    "handlePreflightRequest": (req, res) => {
      res.writeHead(200, {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:3000",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,POST",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "my-custom-header",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true
      });
      res.end();
    }
  }
```

and

```
const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT, {
withCredentials: true,
transportOptions: {
  polling: {
    extraHeaders: {
      "my-custom-header": "abcd"
    }
  }
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I had to do was change EXPO to socket to this:

```
const socket = socketIOClient(ENDPOINT,{
    path: '/ws',

   });
```